# HTML/CSS - Phantom Margin which I can not find

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I'm creating a menu bar on my website. My issue is that there is a small margin at the side of one of my menu items. (I have highlighted this by adding background-color: black; to the container.) I am using safari.

[image: margin issue]

The CSS:

```
.testMenuOption{
  width: calc(100%  /3);
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: table;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what my issue is? I have tried removing the text and it is not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you calculate the width by using 100/3, there will be rounding errors, where as a result the widths wont add up 100% again. What you can do to fix it is to set  the width of two of the .menuOptionsWraps to 33% and one to 34%.

For example by doing so:

```
.menuOptionSelectedWrap {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: -4px;
    background-color: #d6eef2;
    display: table;
}
.menuOptionSelectedWrap:last-of-type {
    width: 34%;
}
```

Comment: `width: 33.33333333%` should work as well, Bootstrap does that for example.

Comment: Surely 33.33333333% is never going to be completely accurate?

Comment: That depends on the total size of the container. If the remaining 0.0000001% of space is less then what it takes the browser to render it as a pixel, i shouldn't be visible. But you can probably already guess how absurdely big such a container must be to render that pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you say,that black line change when window resize.check your css, width: calc(100%  /3);
change the value 3,you will get idea.